# Chrome Extension to withdraw activity log

Tags: chrome, logs, facebook

I need a Google Crome extension for facebook that does the following work:

1. Withdraw from the list "activity log" of my facebook profile people who accept my friend request and insert it into a list by taking the following data in different fields:

   1. name and surname
   2. the date of entry
2. In the list which we will call "list new friends" insert name of editable fields editable so change it if it is the last name first, and I will explain why
   the list must be women only because I want to put each of them in a group, Women's, so I'm going to manually clear the men
   I want to send to each of them a personalized message with the type name
   “maria hello, nice to meet you” ... 
   So the name recognition must be done by selecting the first field name and not the second field where there will be the last

For each item (facebook friend) I would like the following buttons:
Clears(cancel)
sends message with color change for status change
subscribe to my group with change color when writing or not writing

In short, every friend I wish I was sent a personalized message and I would add in my automatically secret group
The sunny secret group of women health and fitness
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a genaric extension called grease monky that will let you inject JS into any site. It's a good excuse to learn JavaScript.